# offset-anchor places svg shape in a wrong position

Tags: animation, svg, offset

I am failing to understand how to change the value of `offset-anchor` match to my expectations.

**Update**. It doesn't seem like Google Chrome [supports `offset-anchor`](https://caniuse.com/?search=offset-anchor) as of 17-12-2022. The ticket to support this property can be found [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=638055&q=%22motion-path%22&can=2) (it boils down to a relatively small [update](https://codereview.chromium.org/2461603003/patch/20001/30011) in .cpp file). The ticket tracking support of the entire [spec](https://drafts.fxtf.org/motion-1/) can be found [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=654664).

I'm drawing an arrow and I'm trying to make the actual anchor (e.g. dot used for moving) to be at the arrow's head, and not the tail.

The example below highlights the default anchor used to move the arrow. If I change the value of `offset-anchor` to, say, `offset-anchor: left` of the arrow it jumps to a weird position. If I set it to `offset-anchor: right`, it disappears completely. Why?

How do I control the value `offset-anchor` in an expected way?

Not sure if I should, but I could probably look into whether `offset-rotate` is what I need. But I really want to understand first what's wrong with my attempts to control `offset-anchor` property.

P.S. My code is based on what I've observed at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/offset-anchor. However, it seems like I am missing something crucial when modelling my animation after example at that page.

```css
<style>
#placeholder {}

#arrow {
  offset-path: path("M275,50 h-200");
  animation: move 3s;
}
    
#offset-anchor-1 {
  offset-path: path("M275,50 h-200");
  animation: move 3s;
}
    
#rectangle {
  offset-path: path("m575,50 h-200");
  animation: move 3s;
}

#offset-anchor-2 {
  offset-path: path("m575,50 h-200");
  animation: move 3s;
}
    
@keyframes move {
  100% {
    offset-distance: 100%;
  }
}
</style>
```

```html
<svg height=100 width=650 viewPort="0 0 100 650" style="border: 1px solid #999">
  <path id="arrow" d="M0,0 h50" stroke-width="2" stroke="black" marker-end="url(#arrow-head)"></path>    
  <path id="travel-path1" d="M275,50 h-200" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="4" stroke="red"></path>
  <circle id="offset-anchor-1" cx="0" cy="0" r="4" fill="red"></circle>
    
  <rect id="rectangle" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="20" fill="yellow" stroke="navy" stroke-width="1"></rect>
  <path id="travel-path2" d="M575,50 h-200" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="4" stroke="red"></path>
  <circle id="offset-anchor-2" cx="0" cy="0" r="4" fill="red"></circle>
  
  <defs>
    <marker id="arrow-head" markerWidth="5" markerHeight="5" refX="2.5" refY="2.5" viewBox="0 0 5 5" orient="auto">
      <polygon points="0,5 1.6666666666666667,2.5 0,0 5,2.5" fill="black"></polygon>
    </marker>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: `offset-anchor`  is a quite new property and **not well supported** [mdn compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/offset-anchor#browser_compatibility) - currently only by firefox. Apparently. keywords like `bottom` `left` etc. don't work well for svg elements (percentage values work in FF). I'm afraid you shouldn't `offset-anchor` at this moment - it's way to unpredictable.

Comment: The inherent problem with a lot of positioning is that SVG and CSS follow different paradigms: CSS starts with a box and describes relations to that box. SVG starts with a coordinate system and describes other coordinate systems in terms of (explicit or implicit) transformations. From my experience, every new property applied to both goes through a period where SVG implementers are not quite sure what to make of the semantic described in the CSS spec.

Comment: @herrstrietzel @ccprog Thank you both! I did some digging, and it is indeed doesn't seem that Chrome has `offset-anchor` officially implemented. I didn't know about it. I will update my question with some links to Chrome bug tracker about this. In the meantime, if you could think of a workaround - please, feel free to submit one 

Comment: Don't know if this won't break soon, but specifying `offset-anchor: top 0px left 50px` actually does what I originally needed.

Answer (score 1):

My way to go about these problems is to firmly stay in the SVG way of describing relations, with coordinate systems.

While traveling along the `offset-path`, the arrow and the rect are drawn in a coordinate system with its origin at the position of the dot. The x axis points in the direction of movement - the implicitely set `offset-rotate: auto` says so. Accordingly, the x axis points left and the y axis points up. Relative to the root coordinate system, it is rotated around by 180°.

If you want to have the arrow marker at the end of the path, and that at the position of the dot, the path needs to end at `0,0`. The beginning should appear away from the direction of movement (to the right), so it needs to have a negative x value. Instead of `d="M0,0 h50"`, write `d="M-50,0 H0"`.

If you want to have the rectangle to the right and above the dot, define it to the left and below the origin of its coordinate system. Instead of `x="0" y="0" width="50" height="20"`, write `x="-50" y="0" width="50" height="20"`.

```css
<style>
#placeholder {}

#arrow {
  offset-path: path("M275,50 h-200");
  animation: move 3s;
}
    
#offset-anchor-1 {
  offset-path: path("M275,50 h-200");
  animation: move 3s;
}
    
#rectangle {
  offset-path: path("m575,50 h-200");
  animation: move 3s;
}

#offset-anchor-2 {
  offset-path: path("m575,50 h-200");
  animation: move 3s;
}
    
@keyframes move {
  100% {
    offset-distance: 100%;
  }
}
</style>
```

```html
<svg height=100 width=650 viewPort="0 0 100 650" style="border: 1px solid #999">
  <path id="arrow" d="M-50,0 H0" stroke-width="2" stroke="black" marker-end="url(#arrow-head)"></path>    
  <path id="travel-path1" d="M275,50 h-200" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="4" stroke="red"></path>
  <circle id="offset-anchor-1" cx="0" cy="0" r="4" fill="red"></circle>
    
  <rect id="rectangle" x="-50" y="0" width="50" height="20" fill="yellow" stroke="navy" stroke-width="1"></rect>
  <path id="travel-path2" d="M575,50 h-200" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="4" stroke="red"></path>
  <circle id="offset-anchor-2" cx="0" cy="0" r="4" fill="red"></circle>
  
  <defs>
    <marker id="arrow-head" markerWidth="5" markerHeight="5" refX="2.5" refY="2.5" viewBox="0 0 5 5" orient="auto">
      <polygon points="0,5 1.6666666666666667,2.5 0,0 5,2.5" fill="black"></polygon>
    </marker>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to address the original issue by specifying the `offset-anchor` like this:

```
offset-anchor: top 0px left 50px
```

This works as expected in Chrome 108. However, as pointed out in an update to the text of original question, `offset-anchor` doesn't seem to be supported officially.